# How to ingest error logs from processors to database table

Tags: database, logging, apache-nifi

I want to add all my failure logs to a column in DB.

As I am new to nigi. I'm confused on how to do that.

Need suggestion on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps outlined below.

1. Under `Controller Settings`, add a `REPORTING TASKS` of type `SiteToSiteBulletinReportingTask`. This will capture bulletins. Make sure that `Input Port Name` property value is exact same as input port created at step 2. Configure rest of properties accordingly.
2. Add an input port at root level of NiFi i.e. not inside any process group.

When you start the reporting task, it will start sending bulletins to configured input port, i.e. NiFi instance will send data to itself, and you can further ingest into database.

Have a look at these implementation resources,

- https://medium.com/@ashish211981/nifi-monitoring-driven-development-6b21046ee9e4
- https://www.clearpeaks.com/health-monitoring-of-nifi-flows-using-bulletin-events/

Comment: Hi Vikram, I am actually getting empty [] JSON from server and when it goes to Split after Invokehttp there is no further flow from split. So I want to send a custom message to DB table after Invokehttp whenever I'm getting empty JSON. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: You can check content/attribute of FlowFile came out of `InvokeHTTP` processor and based on logic route FlowFile using `RouteOnAttribute`/`RouteOnContent` accordingly. To put into database use `PutSQL`.

Comment: Hi Vikram., I have tried your approach and now I am able to capture the errors but  the values for bulletinNodeAddress"  and "bulletinNodeId" are showing null.
 I am using local host 8080.

Comment: These attributes are from which processor?

Comment: these are from bulletin board, I am confused where they are coming from. All the other details like processor group id and name , error message are showing but only these two attributes are showing null.