# in Apache nifi v1.15 processor error message as flow file attribute

Tags: apache-nifi

how can I get the error message as flow file attribute if the publish to Kafka processor gets failed
a guidance to create a Nifi flow if the publish to Kafka files need to get the failed time and error message and loaded the attributes to sql server tables

Comment: Refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75376293/how-to-ingest-error-logs-from-processors-to-database-table